# Include Custom DLL's in Visual Studio Project Template

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am trying to create a project template in Visual Studio 2008 and have had success in doing so.

Is it possible to include some custom assemblies in my project template so I don't have to add a reference to these assemblies once I instantiate a new project?  If this is possible, how would I go about do this?

Comment: To clarify - it looks like the OP wants to EMBED the dependency DLLs in the project template zip files ASWELL as have them referenced by the project. I am struggling with this myself at the moment - because Visual Studio ignores any files in the zip which are not <Content> items in the csproj file - hence <Reference> items dont make the cut! argh!

Comment: ...linking the DLLs into the project is one way to force them to be extracted by VS when the user chooses to create a new instance of the Project. Its kinda ugly though.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this myself. The best way to do it today, is to create a nuget package which contains all your 'content' - such as DLLs. Then add the nuget package wizard to the WizardExtension section of your vstemplate, and add your nuget package (as either a reference to an online repository, or the actual embedded .nupkg file)...

Your nuget package will be packaged in your final VSIX file - so rolling everything out into a Visual Studio deployment will be a simple double click.
What will happen when a developer creates a new project based on your template, is the project structure will be created, then Visual Studio will see there is a Nuget dependency, and it will automatically install your nuget package into the new template, and add the appropriate references to the project.

Here are a couple of fully fleshed out explanations of how to achieve this - Marcin's example has a downloadable zip example (you can find the link in his comments):

[Kedar R Kulkarni](http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2012/01/20/Creating-custom-project-template-for-Visual-Studio-with-pre-installed-NuGet-packages.aspx)

[Marcin Doboz](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/07/08/project-templates-and-preinstalled-nuget-packages.aspx)

Comment: So if you want to use this (seamingly best) solution in production, you should have you own internal nuget feeds/gallery which has various other benefits.

Comment: Just to clarify mbx's comment - a good practice is to have your package published to a repository - however it is not required, because you can include your nupkg file (the actual compressed package) in your project template - meaning everything is completely self contained. See Marcin's article, specifically the section "Template package repository"

Comment: As  complementry source :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/visual-studio-templates

Answer (score 0):

Yes update the project file in the template in the zip file. Or use the export to template in vs with the reference already included.  [link text](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsstart/thread/e7b4914f-0f35-4ca6-b5fb-003e766bb604) will make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Look to this msdn page: 
"How to: Add Templates to the New Project Dialog Box"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166808.aspx

Comment: The link doesn't say a word about DLLs, LIB files or other custom items.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the DLL to your project folder somewhere, add the DLL to your solution (add existing item, set filter to *.dll manually), and then add a reference to that copy in your project settings.  It should be stored in your exported project template so long as you do that first.