# Missing .lib files from exported Visual Studio template

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2019, lib

I'm creating a template C++ project for Visual Studio that requires some .lib and .dll files. The files are linked to in the project properties linker settings and included in the dependencies and also included in the project via the Solution Explorer. Everything runs fine, but when I export the project to a template and use that template to create a new project the .lib files are the only ones missing.

I've tried extracting the .zip of the exported template, adding the .lib files manually and their paths to the .vstemplate, then re-zipping the project, but this hasn't worked either.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 if that's relevant.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779505/include-custom-dlls-in-visual-studio-project-template

Comment: @engf-010 Thanks, I've had a look at this post, but some of the links are no longer available. Will have a look at nuget anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, as mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779505/include-custom-dlls-in-visual-studio-project-template), the best way is to create a nuget package which contains all your 'content' - such as DLLs.

Of course, there is another way:

1. Create a `Dependencies` folder under the project directory, put the required dlls and libs.
2. Set `Proeperties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories->(SolutionDir)Dependencies\..` and `Proeperties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories->$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\..` in your project template.

For example:
[image]

[image]

3. When you use the project template, copy the `Dependencies` folder to your new project directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Up to now I have more or less been doing this, but copying the directory manually every time I start a new project is kind of annoying. I wonder if this could be done with a pre-build command alternatively? Either way I will probably have to look into nuget.

Comment: Using [xcpoy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) is similar to manual copying. So, I suggest that you could use nuget.

Answer (score 0):

1. create the exported template and then navigate to
   **C:\Users%UserName%\Documents\Visual Studio
   2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates** and find the .zip file with your
   template.
2. unzip the template.
3. add the missing .lib files to their location inside the template
   folder structure.
4. open with a text editor the **MyTemplate.vstemplate** file.
5. locate `<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="main.cpp">main.cpp</ProjectItem>`
6. using the same format include a line for each .lib file you need to include, e.g. `<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="glfw3.lib">DEPENDENCIES\GLFW\lib-vc2022\glfw3.lib</ProjectItem>`
7. open with a text editor the **Template.vcxproj** file.
8. find where the Include files are referenced and add a line for each .lib file, e.g. `<ClInclude Include="Dependencies\GLEW\lib\Release\x64\glew32.lib" />`
9. save the files, recompress to a zip file and replace the template zip in the initial location.

Now you will be able to create a new project from this template and it will include the .lib files