# Leading-dot files missing from custom Visual Studio template

Tags: gitignore, visual-studio-templates

I've created a custom [Visual Studio template](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates) containing an ASP.NET Core+angular application. But when I create a new project using this template, the files starting with `.` are missing from the generated project.

These are the files in the **ClientApp** folder of the template project:

[image: The template project folder contains files with a leading dot]

But when I package the template project, install them using

```
dotnet new --install MintPlayer.AspNetCore.IdentityServer.Templates
```

These files are missing from the generated project:

[image: The generated project doesn't contain the files starting with a dot]

I've already taken a look at the following, but without success:

- [Missing .lib files from exported Visual Studio template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66277149/missing-lib-files-from-exported-visual-studio-template)

When I run

```
dotnet pack --configuration Release
```

I can see the following printed in the console:

```
C:\...\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5):
warning NU5119: File 'C:\repos\Example.AspNetCore.Templates\Example.AspNetCore.Templates\Templates\Application\Web\ClientApp\node_modules\resolve\.editorconfig' was not added to the package. Files and folders starting with '.' or ending with '.nupkg' are excluded by default. To include this file, use -NoDefaultExcludes from the commandline [C:\...\Example.AspNetCore.Templates.csproj]
```

How can I include these files anyway in my package as "Content"?

References:

- [.NET project templates (angular/react)](https://github.com/dotnet/spa-templates)
- [Another example template repository](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/template-sample)
- [Third example template repository for .NET](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
<NoDefaultExcludes>true</NoDefaultExcludes>
```

To the root `csproj` file solved the issue

The spa-templates repository [does the same](https://github.com/dotnet/spa-templates/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates.csproj#L8)